# Params not being read in controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am setting up a state picker drop down the end goal is for the user to choose a state and the select tag below to populate with cities for that state im using the city-state gem https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state

I have gotten the correct parameters in my request but they are not being read by the controller method.

**registrations-controller.rb**

```
def new
  super
  @cities = CS.get(:us,params[:state]) 
  puts @cities                 
end
```

this is not picking up the :state param

**new.html.erb**

```
 <%= select_tag :state,options_for_select(CS.states(:us)), 
  {:class => "signup-input-container--input", :id => "state-picker"} %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_scope :family do
  get 'states', to: 'families/registrations#new'
end
```

**main.js**

```
  var state = document.getElementById("state-picker");
  state.addEventListener("change", function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: "/states?state=" + state.value,
        type: "GET"
     })
  })
```

Anyone know why this is happening? I also logged the params and got.

```
 "<ActionController::Parameters {"state"=>"Colorado", "controller"=>"families/registrations", "action"=>"new"} permitted: false> "
```

Comment: I'd consider doing `puts params` and seeing what is available  when `RegistrationsController#new` is called. That information might help us realise what's going on, and would be useful to include in your question.

Comment: hey @david thanks for the quick response i logged params.inspect and got "<ActionController::Parameters {"state"=>"Colorado", "controller"=>"families/registrations", "action"=>"new"} permitted: false>
"

Comment: Does the drop-down currently display state names or two-letter codes?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state#list-of-cities) suggest that the `cities` method wants a symbol for the state. You're using the [simplified](https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state#simplified-syntax-with-get-method) `get` method but it probably also wants a symbol instead of the name of the city as a String (which is what we can see in your `params`).

So maybe main.js should have the following:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/states?state=" + state.key, // 'state.value' was the string of the state name, we want the two-letter code.
    type: "GET"
 })
```

You'll probably also have to change this line

```
@cities = CS.get(:us,params[:state])
```

to this

```
@cities = CS.get(:us,params[:state].to_s)
```

Comment: I'd say the problem is that we need to get the 2-letter code out of the select (we're currently getting the city name). I'm not sure I've suggested the right code changes, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you get `permitted: false` in `ActionController::Parameters` it's probably because you are not whitelisting your parameters (`:state` in this case) in your controller, like required by [Strong Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

From the docs:

> With strong parameters, Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been whitelisted.

Example:

```
private
  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
  end
```